# erlang ssl and {ssl_closed, Socket}

Tags: erlang

I have two erlang nodes running in two different computers, in one node I have an ssl client and in the other i have the ssl server. Both computers are connected to the Internet via wifi connection.

Everything works right, but I wonder why if I switch off the wifi in the client laptop I don't receive the {ssl_closed, Socket} message.

Socket options are:

```
{active, true}, {keepalive, true}
```

I mean, the socket should not be valid anymore..right?

Comment: Do you know what the keep alive timeout is set to on your system? For example, my fedora linux uses 7200 seconds (2 hours).

Comment: nope i don't know, how can i know it? and set it as well..thanks!

Comment: Added answer with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global TCP keepalive timeout value is typically set to a value like 7200 seconds between the keepalive messages. If you are on a Linux system you can check it with `sysctl -a | grep keepalive`.

Fiddling with this value is not really recommended since it is a global configuration. Instead you should add a `ping` message to your application level protocol (letting the client send pings now and then), the server can simply discard it.

It seems to be possible to set per-socket keepalive timeouts through the `inet:setopts/2` function and using the `raw`option, but I don't know if that is recommended (it's not portable between platforms)